# Disable app interaction with user on internet connection lost android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I'm creating an app the must have internet connection,
and if the connection is lost, i need to disable any interaction with the user.

I do that by listening to android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.
which works great.

I want to put an alert dialog and gray the whole background from the BroadcastReceiver.

[image: No internet connection]

anyway to make that happen?

Thanks.

Shahar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to know,
i used broadcast receiver on my main activity.

```
/*
    here we handle connection lost event
    show a popup over the screen to notify the user
 */
static final String ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionReceiver";

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    public ConnectionReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isConnected) {
                try {
                    if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing())
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (alertDialog == null || !alertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("No internet connection");
                    builder.setMessage("check your connection.");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```